# Font Weight Shift on loading Nextjs

Tags: css, next.js, tailwind-css, server-side-rendering

I use Next.js and Tailwind CSS for my app. When I set Chrome DevTools to 'Fast 3G', I notice the weight shift... I've encountered this issue on various websites without 'Fast 3G' enabled. However, I haven't found any solution for it yet

I have added this style like on the [vercel.com](https://vercel.com/home) website. But I doubt I forgot something...

```js
const inter = Inter({ 
    subsets: ['latin'],
    variable: "--font-sans",
    display: "swap"
})

<body className={`${inter.variable} text-foreground font-sans bg-background antialiased`}>
```

### When it's load

[image: When it's load]

### After load

[image: After Load]

Comment: `font-display: swap` tells the browser to use a fallback font immediately while the specified font is being downloaded. So my best guess is the browser has the font but only at one weight, and needs to download the additional weight. Look at using `preload` and `font-display: optional`, https://leerob.io/blog/fonts

Comment: As commented it's a font shift not a weight shift. To mitigate this problem you may also consider to load a static bold version (provided you need only a few weights) of Inter as variable fonts are larger in filesize than single weight ones. Also make sure you're loading the most compact woff2 format.